# Mysql query enhancement for union

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query that will be used for reports and i have a lot of data.
As of the moment is this my query that uses of `UNION ALL` over `UNION` because i remembered last project i used the `UNION` is that it dont unite all the datas and i never knew why so i used the `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT `item_id`, NULL AS `ob`,SUM(`add`) AS `add` ,NULL AS `dam`,NULL AS `sold`,NULL AS `others`,NULL AS `ac`
          FROM (
            -- DELIVERED ITEMS
            SELECT si.`item_id`,SUM(sdi.`actual_pcs`) AS `add`
            FROM `store_inventory` si
            LEFT JOIN `store_delivery` sd
            ON sd.`store_id` = si.`store_id` AND DATE(sd.`dt_modified`) = '2018-09-01'
            AND sd.`status` = "DONE"
            LEFT JOIN `store_delivery_items` sdi
            ON sdi.`strd_id` = sd.`strd_id` AND sdi.`item_id` = si.`item_id`
            WHERE si.`store_id` = '4'
            GROUP BY si.`item_id`

            UNION ALL

            -- OVERRIDE ADD (ADD)
            SELECT si.`item_id`,SUM(oi.`qty`) AS `add`
            FROM `store_inventory` si
            LEFT JOIN `override` o
            ON o.`ref_id` = si.`store_id`
            AND o.`type` = "STORE"
            AND o.`action` = "ADD"
            AND DATE(o.`dt_created`) = '2018-09-01'
            LEFT JOIN `override_items` oi
            ON oi.`item_id` = si.`item_id`
            AND oi.`ovr_id` = o.`ovr_id`
            WHERE si.`store_id` = '4'
            GROUP BY si.`item_id`

            UNION ALL

            -- CANCELLED SALES (ADD)
            SELECT si.`item_id`,SUM(sai.`si_qty`) AS `add`
            FROM `store_inventory` si
            LEFT JOIN `sales` s
            ON s.`sales_store_id` = si.`store_id`
            AND s.`cancelled_by` IS NOT NULL
            AND DATE(s.`dt_cancelled`) = '2018-09-01'
            LEFT JOIN `sales_items` sai
            ON sai.`si_sales_id` = s.`sales_id`
            AND sai.`si_item_id` = si.`item_id`
            WHERE si.`store_id` = '4' 
            GROUP BY si.`item_id`

            UNION ALL

            -- PULLOUT REJECTED ADDED BACK TO STORE (ADD)
            SELECT si.`item_id`,SUM(poi.`poi_actual`) AS `add`
            FROM `store_inventory` si
            LEFT JOIN `pullout` p
            ON p.`pullout_reason` IN ("STORE TO DAMAGE","STORE TO WAREHOUSE")
            AND p.`pullout_status` IN ("REJECT","HEAD-REJECTED")
            AND DATE(p.`dt_modified`) = '2018-09-01'
            AND p.`pullout_from` = si.`store_id`
            LEFT JOIN `pullout_items` poi
            ON poi.`poi_item_id` = si.`item_id`
            AND poi.`poi_pullout_id` = p.`pullout_id`
            WHERE si.`store_id` = '4'
            GROUP BY si.`item_id`
          ) AS add_temp
          GROUP BY `item_id`
```

As you can see i loop all my table from my store inventory items this is only a one day report because i do the loop in php for date ranges. Im wondering if this query can be enhanced more. I tried the left join all over my tables and i got no luck. Is this the right query for this kind of reporting? this is just part my query BTW. I still have this `openingbalance,damaged,sold,others` query as you can see in my `SELECT` statement. So i really need an advise regarding with this long query. I already added indeces of my columns to my tables in order to select results faster.

Comment: `UNION` removes all the duplicates, while `UNION ALL` does not do any such checks

Comment: thank you for enlighting me with those two. so I really need the union all. because I need to add the sum of all. btw, do you have any suggestions to enhance my query or that's the right way? or will it be more faster if I create a vmysql view for that?

Comment: I am thinking you are on the right way; as I have also used a similar approach few months back to create an Inventory report (detailing about all stock in and stock out phenomenon)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Okay thank you. your comment is very much appreciated